# Woocommerce rest api filter on category parent id

Tags: react-native, woocommerce-rest-api

I am developing a react native app for woocommerce store. the scenario is that i have a multi vendor store at the first page I display the restaurants once a user click on a restaurant the categories of food the restaurant sell shows up the problem is I have some parent category like Fast Food, Arabian...etc. and have some child categories assign to the the parent categories like

1. FastFood:

   - Burgers.
   - Pizza

now my restaurant endpoint gave me the parent id of the category now i want to sent a request to the server to gave me the child category of the parent assign to the restaurant.
I am trying this url
"https://mystore.com/wp-json/wp/v3/products/categories/?filter[parent]=371&${consumerkey}&${cumsumersecret}"
but this url returns all of the categories. can any one help me how to filter woocommerce api categories on bases of its parent id.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So if i'm understanding this correctly,

Here's the request to get the child

```
/wp/v3/categories?parent=ID
```

Another fun solution that would be less confusing might be to actually instead of the main categories asign Things like Fast Food|Arabian as a Tag Pull all the tags in the main page And then use categories to define from there.

Heres a Example of how to get the tags

```
/wp-json/wc/v3/products/tags/<id>
```